# LinkPoint payment integration with IIS6 on windows server 2003 crashes w3wp.exe

Tags: w3wp.exe, linkpoint

I am using the LinkPointTransaction.dll from FirstData to process credit card transactions. As the code is running, a call to the LinkPointTransaction.LinkPointTxn.Send() sends the transaction successfully to FirstData over the internet, but my application crashes w3wp.exe somewhere during  that call, before it hits the next line. It does not throw a managed exception that I can see; it just crashes. The problem is it works fine when I run it on VS development server. After some research I found that when I recycle the ApplicationPool, the first time I try to access the application, it fails [basically ends the w3wp.exe process]. And then the w3wp.exe is restarted. From here on the application works for sometime and fails again eventually. So anyone have any idea whats going on??

Comment: I'd say that this is probably something you need to throw back at LinkPoint, or whoever it is who wrote the .dll

Comment: I tried that, they are suggesting that the problem is with my application and I don't know how to fix this thing!!

Comment: just an update, i contacted FirstData again today and now they say their DLLs are not compatible with .NET 4.0!! So, I guess that's it. Worst customer support ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DLLs are not compatible with .NET 4.0!!!

Answer (score 0):

I asked First Data about the DLLs and being able to run it on IIS7/.NET 4/Win 2008 64-bit. This was their response:

> Thank you for your recent inquiry regarding First Data Global Gateway.   The  Webservice API is our current solution for 64 bit machines running on IIS 7 as none of the dll files (Linkpointtransaction.dll, LPICOM_6_.dll) will be updated to work with the 64bit server.  Webservice API will require to install the client certificate and send the transaction via SOAP request.  Additional information on Webservice API is found at http://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/FDGG-Web-Service-API-v4.0.pdf.
>
> If you need further clarifications or questions, please contact our support desk via phone number below.  Please be advised the API support desk hours is from 9:00AM to 6:00PM EST Mon-Fri.

This should help others looking for similar information in the future.